# SQL Case inequality

Tags: sql, case, inequality

Currently I am using

```
If @City > 0 then
    SELECT * FROM table1 Where Column1 < @City
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM table1
```

How can I achieve the same effect in a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply put the condition in the query:

```
select *
  from table1
 where ( @city > 0
         and column1 < @city )
    or @city <= 0
```

Be warned though; this *can* confuse the optimizer slightly which might make your first query less performant. As with everything test before implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
  from table1
 where column1 < @city
    or @city <= 0
```

Comment: Thnx. All the answers achieved the results I was looking for

Comment: @Rohan But, obviously, my are shortest :)

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE Column1 < CASE WHEN @City > 0 
                     THEN @City 
                     ELSE Column1 + 1 END
```